# Filter DataGridView through textbox and stored procedure

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a DataGridView that is populated through a stored procedure. I'd like to be able to filter the DataGridView by typing in a textbox, but I'm faily new to C# so I'm struggling to figure out how to get this to work.

I have a stored procedure that grabs data from two tables in my database, which runs this query:

```
    SELECT l.LocationID,
            l.LocationName,
            g.GameName
    FROM dbo.Locations l 
    JOIN dbo.Games g
        ON g.GameID = l.GameID
    ORDER BY l.LocationName
```

My Windows form app uses the following code to populate the DataGridView:

```
public static void fillLocations(DataGridView dgv)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = (local); Database = DBName; Integrated Security = SSPI;"))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sGetLocations", con))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                            {
                                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                                da.Fill(dt);

                                dgv.DataSource = dt;
                                dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
                                dgv.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                                dgv.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                                dgv.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I'd like to have two text boxes on my form so I can filter the DataGridView by searching for a game name or location name. Ideally, when a location or game name is entered into a textbox it will filter the results to show only locations or games with that name, but I'm not sure what is the best way to achieve this with my code.

### Edit

I've now amended my stored procedure to filter by either a game or location parameter

```
    SELECT l.LocationID,
            l.LocationName,
            g.GameName
    FROM dbo.Locations l 
    JOIN dbo.Games g
        ON g.GameID = l.GameID
    WHERE g.GameName LIKE '%' + @GameName + '%'
    OR l.LocationName LIKE '%' + @LocationName + '%'
```

I have also written a different method that is called on the TextChanged event for my search text box

```
 public static void filterLocations(DataGridView dgv, TextBox tloc, TextBox tgam)
        {
            using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("Server = (local); Database = BoneFish; Integrated Security = SSPI;"))
            {
                using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
                {
                    try
                    {
                        con.Open();

                        using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("sFilterLocations", con))
                        {
                            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@LocationName", tloc.Text);
                            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GameName", tgam.Text);

                            using (SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter())
                            {
                                da.SelectCommand = cmd;
                                da.Fill(dt);

                                dgv.DataSource = dt;
                                dgv.Columns[0].HeaderText = "ID";
                                dgv.Columns[0].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                                dgv.Columns[1].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
                                dgv.Columns[2].AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.DisplayedCells;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

I don't get any errors when running the app but nothing happens when typing in the search textbox.

Answer (score 0):

You need set N parameters in your stored procedure (same that filters column)

Code C#:

```
    SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand(commandText, connection);
    command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int);
    command.Parameters["@ID"].Value = customerID;
```

And sql:

```
    SELECT l.LocationID,
        l.LocationName,
        g.GameName
FROM dbo.Locations l 
JOIN dbo.Games g
    ON g.GameID = l.GameID
WHERE g.GameName like '%' + @GameNameParam + '%'
ORDER BY l.LocationName
```

For more information:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-en/dotnet/api/system.data.sqlclient.sqlcommand.parameters?view=netframework-4.8

Good weekend!

Comment: Thanks for your help Ruben. I've made some changes using your suggestions but it's not working as expected. I've updated my question with the new code and details and was wondering if you had any thoughts?